# On first click animation works good, on second it skips some steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, velocity.js

For this animation I use [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) and here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shrink').on('click', function() {
        $(".spread").removeClass("spread").addClass("shrink");
        $(this).removeClass("shrink").addClass("spread");
        $(".spread").velocity({
            width: "80%"
        }, 300);
        $(".shrink").velocity({
            width: "5%"
        }, 300);
        $('.spread').on('click', function() {
            $(this).removeClass("spread").addClass("shrink");
            $(".shrink").velocity({
                width: "20%"
            }, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

and the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hrv5u8z/) with full animation preview.

So, when you click on some column it opens and click again it closes. That is how it is supposed to work. But, the problem is if you now click **again** on the **same** column, it will open and close immediately, which is not the effect I want.

How can I fix this?

Btw, not sure why, but currently is not working in chrome, but it works in ff.

Comment: i have to inform you one thing, this is not working in google chrome like you said.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include velocity.js, please adjust

Comment: every time you click you're adding more and more handlers to the element you click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

simple rewrite of your code becomes

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on('click', '.spread', function () {
        $(this).removeClass("spread").addClass("shrink");
        $(".shrink").velocity({
            width: "20%"
        }, 300);
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.shrink', function () {

        $(".spread").removeClass("spread").addClass("shrink");

        $(this).removeClass("shrink").addClass("spread");

        $(".spread").velocity({
            width: "80%"
        }, 300);

        $(".shrink").velocity({
            width: "5%"
        }, 300);


    });

});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1hrv5u8z/1/)

Comment: That works! I will check the link you sent me, I am still very new with javascript and I have lots more to learn. I don't understand why we use `body` as trigger but I will try to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't have to be body - on the fiddle could just as easily have used `".row"` ... a common ancestor to the panels you are interested in - like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hrv5u8z/3/)

Comment: Aha, okay, I understand now. :)